# Form in magento stopped working after updating theme

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, magento

ran into an issue here and i hope you guys can help! 
i updated my site's theme last night and now when i click on "ask a question" on product page, the form is not loaded and instead "#question-in-page "

appears on my url as if nothing was clicked. 
sites page is: 
http://www.ahfashion.com/hardwick-2-button-navy-suit-100-worsted-wool.html

your help would be appreciated.

Comment: restore theme from back up edit again. reCap at bottom of page? im guessing you messes up some js.

Comment: Yes, think the same. Should a popup appear after clicking the link? Tell us what you try to do...